# Google search Console API return 404

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-search-console

I would like to simply fetch some data from Google Search Console via API. I am struggling with Oauth2 for days but to be hones I don't really know what is it, and how it should be used. I don't really mind about security, it is not a super secret project, so I am trying to get some data with a simple API key, but it doesn't work neither. 
I have an API key what I generated in Google Cloud Console
[image]
I am trying to get data with Postman based on [this example,](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/searchanalytics) but I always get 404 error. 
[image]

**Can you help me what do I wrong? It shouldn't be so complicated. **

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong url; `webmaster` should be `webmasters`. See [here](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3)

Additionally, once you solve that you will get a 401 using only an API token. You need to use OAuth. If you want this to run regularly, you can authorize it once with an account and use something called a refresh [token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2).